# How find a file with part of his name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and on StackOverflow.

I'm trying to write a script which gives me the Total Path to a `*.pdf` file,
My File Name is in a variable (I get it before with previous part of code) for example : `$myVariable.Nom`

After I try to find my file with this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter $myVariable.Nom
```

But it doesn't work. I think I have a mistake where I try to filter with my File Name in the ChildItem command but don't know how to use it correctly.

The goal is `(if myVariable.Nom = "TOTO" for example)` to have `c:\myPath\TOTO.pdf`

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `-Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*.*"` if you don't know the extension. `-Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*.pdf"` if you want pdf only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Filter` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` supports a wildcard search using `*` or `?`. Your code is pretty close to what you're looking for, you just need to add `*`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*"
```

Note that I'm using `*` at the beginning and end of the variable, **meaning that the filter should search for any Item that contains the string in your variable.**

In your example, you know that the File Name is `TOTO` so you could use `*` only at the end of the `Filter`:

```
-Filter "$($myVariable.Nom)*"
```

Remember that you can add the `-Recurse` flag on `Get-ChildItem` if you want to search recursively.

Now if you want to get the `FullName` (Total Path) you can use any of the examples below:

```
# Example 1
(Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*").FullName

# Example 2
$var = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*"
$var.FullName

# Example 3
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter "*$($myVariable.Nom)*" |
Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

#### Edit

Following your second question, how to deal with a CSV with no headers:

```
$path = 'C:\path\to\csv.csv'

# Note: I'm using -Delimiter ';' because as you have shown,
# you are using semicolon as delimiter, however, if the delimiter
# are commas there is no need to use it.

$csv = Import-Csv $path -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Name','Qte'

# Now you can loop through it to find the files:

foreach($file in $csv)
{
    $var = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myPath\" -Filter "*$($file.Name)*"
    0..$file.Qte | foreach-object {
        $var.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help @YoanLILA ;)

Comment: Final step : i have to print the file i get in $var.FullName as many time as the number in the 2sd Collumn "Qte". So i use this command :  # Start-Process -FilePath $var.FullName -Verb PrintTo '\\srv-print\myPrinter -PassThru ..but don't know how to set the parameter for the quantity ?

Comment: @YoanLILA last edit, i'm starting to think this was your homework :)

Comment: Ah ah not homework just work ^^  just i'm not a dev but i have to do this :(

Comment: Ah ah not homework just work ^^  just i'm not a dev just an network and systèm Administrator. I have linux script who did thas and i try to remplace it by powershell script. ;)  But i don't understand  your last edit " 0..$file

Comment: @YoanLILA 0..X is a way to loop X number of times (from 0 to X), since `$file.Qte` will hold a number as you have shown on your CSV, it will do `from 0 to $file.Qte`

Comment: Ok so it work well but i write 1..X for have the good quantity ;) Thank's a lot for your answers

Comment: No problem, happy to help @YoanLILA

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers : It's work fine !!

Now i want to improve it a litle bit : In my CSV i have 2 column : in the previous example i called the first column "Name" this is why i used myVariable.Name)  for example:

```
Name;Qte
TOTO;1
TITI;3
```

Now how i can select the first column if i didn't have name on first line ?
file like this one for example :

```
TOTO;1
TITI;3
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean, how to deal with a CSV that doesn't any headers. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: There you go, check the edit on my answer.